# SharePoint Permission Clean Up - Cannot find group/user

Tags: 2013, permissions

I've been working on cleaning up SharePoint permissions within a SharePoint 2013 environment. Generally it's quite easy to find the users however I am having an incredibly tough time with one group and user.

In the screenshot below, it tells me the permissions they've got but not what group it is coming from. I've checked to see if they're Site Collection admins and they are not in that group and I looked at the Farm admin group and I cannot see them there.

Any advice on where to look will be truly appreciated.

[image: SharePoint Permissions Check]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone else suffering this issue of trying to find the permissions for a user if they're not in the Farm or Site Collection admin area.

Check the User Policy for the Web Application in Central Admin.

Answer (score 0):

The above permission are for the user account who is given site collection admin.

Please go to the site collection administrator from site setting (site collection) you will find the  **portal sharepoint support**.

Comment: Hey Sunil, the Site Collection Admin section didn't have them but I found out that for some reason the user was added in the Web Application Administrator section. I only just found this now, why the user would be added here is beyond me.